# Is there any way to record all keys of cache misses in Ignite?

Tags: ignite

I am facing a problem with hit-rate of Ignite through the below metrics exposed by Ignite
`org_apache_dmp_user_mask_CacheHitPercentage{name="\"org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheClusterMetricsMXBeanImpl\"",} 98.48369598388672 org_apache_dmp_user_mask_CacheHitPercentage{name="\"org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLocalMetricsMXBeanImpl\"",} 99.72936248779297`

Although I tried to fulfill all data in a cache that will be used for serving requests, however somehow at the midnight (from 2 am to 5 am), the hit-rate reduced significantly.
[hit-rate chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EckAq.png)

So I'd like to record those cases for troubleshooting and understand what is happening at the midnight.
Anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Write your own implementation of `CacheStore` (or rather extend the one that you're using currently). The method [`load`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/integration/CacheLoader.html#load(K)) or [`loadAll`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/integration/CacheLoader.html#loadAll(java.lang.Iterable)) will be called whenever the system reads a key from the 3rd party storage. You can log the key there before reading the external key.